# Method overloading in a model of Yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I want to overload two methods in a model of Yii framework.

Here, I want to say that like in Java we have method overloading concept means method has same name but differs in number of parameters pass to that method. So these similar concept can apply in PHP Yii framework's model class.
In Yii model class, I want to create two methods like,

```
public function test(){ 
   //method logic
}
public function test(int parameters){
  //method logic
}
```

Is it possible to create like these? I am getting error like "cannot define same function".

Comment: PHP doesn't support method overloading. I assume you mean something different, but it's unclear, what you want to achieve.

Comment: You can use code to detect the type of the data passed to your methods (or use defaults for no parameters), ex. `is_array`, `is_object`, etc and provide the right type of output. This is the closest I know of method overloading in php

Comment: i think what you are talking about isn't exactly method **overloading** but it's **method overriding**. so let us know your exact requirement, or atleast some sample code the way you think you want to do it. we can help you correct it, if needed ofcourse.

Comment: @bool.dev: Nice distinction. I kick a puppy when other PHPers tell me they are overloading a method.

Answer (score 3):

What you are talking about is not supported in PHP. You could try using default values in [function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php). For eg.

```
function foo($int_param = 0) // do something
```

You could also use [func_get_args](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php). You define your function to not accept parameters and then get the arguments using func_get_args().

These approaches are suitable if there is not a lot of difference between the functions that you're trying to implement.