# Yii - using a single method for both AJAX update/create

Tags: php, ajax, yii, overloading

I have set up this method for updating a model via AJAX, and have tried to extend it by also creating a new model if it doesn't exist.

```
public function actionAjaxUpdate($id = null)
{
    if($id === null)
        $model = new MyObject;
    else
        $model = $this->loadModel($id);

    if(isset($_POST['MyObject']))
    {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['MyObject'];
        $model->save();
    }
}
```

Sample URLs sent when updating via AJAX, the digits at the end being the model ID:

```
/admin/myObject/ajaxUpdate/1
/admin/myObject/ajaxUpdate/2
/admin/myObject/ajaxUpdate/3
...
```

The problem here is that while updating works fine as an ID is provided, creating a new model doesn't work. Because the ID does not exist yet for new items, the URL route will return a 404:

> The requested URL /cmsadmin/myObject/ajaxUpdate was not found on this
>   server.

*What would be a good approach to solving this problem?*

I have tried overloading the same method without the `$id` parameter, but PHP does not support overloading, as discussed in this thread: [Method overloading in a model of Yii framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335589/method-overloading-in-a-model-of-yii-framework)

*Please leave a comment if any additional information is required.*

==== Additional Information ====

**main.php**

```
<?php
$backend = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$frontend = dirname($backend);
Yii::setPathOfAlias('admin', $backend);

return array(
    'basePath' => $frontend,
    'controllerPath' => $backend . '/controllers',
    'viewPath' => $backend . '/views',
    'runtimePath' => $backend . '/runtime',

    'components' => array(
        'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'caseSensitive' => false,
            'appendParams' => true,
            'rules' => array(
                'admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'/<controller>/<action>',
                'admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'/<controller>/<action>',
...
```

Comment: url rules look fine. btw the urls begin with cmsadmin or admin? correct the typo, incase it is one. the action also looks fine. you shouldn't be getting the 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem but I passed in the `id=0` for insert and `id=1` for update. Make sure the id field is set to auto-increment so it is not required.

Now check if id is 1 then do insert else update the record.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like Boniface suggested, pass 0 as the id, but you will have to change your function to

```
if($id == 0)
```

In this way if you pass 0 as the id, it will detect that and create a new object.

Or you can pass nothing (or 0) and just use

```
if(!$id) {
    $model = new MyObject;
```